# Best way of implementing a web method with multiple calls to another web service web method

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

Can someone please suggest best way to implement the below scenario.

1. I have two web services, websvc1 and websvc2 with methods, websvc1.webmethod1() and websvc2.webmethod2()
2. websvc2.webmethod2() needs to call websvc1.webmethod1() some 500 times in a for loop.
3. The call from websvc2.webmethod() should not wait for response from websvc1.webmthod1()
4. Also the websvc1.webmethod1() registers for few events which will be triggered for almost 60k times and this should be done asynchronously.

By the way these two are WCF services.

Comment: "optimize the performance" "some 500 times in a for loop" --- these 2 requirements barely can live together.

Comment: I have 60k records in DB and I can pass 300 records each time from websvc2 to websvc1 as I get maximum size exceeded exception if I pass more than 300. Hence those many calls.. any other ideas for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Does websvc2.webmethod2() care if the call to websvc1.webmethod1() fails? If so then I would suggest making 500 calls in a loop will have to be done synchronously, as the caller will need to know if the call fails. This could be done multithreaded, but there's not much point as the bottleneck here will not be how quickly you can call websvc1.webmethod1(), but how fast websvc1.webmethod1() can process the calls.

If not then in my opinion you would be well advised to make websvc1.webmethod1() a one way call, and use a queued binding.

To do this, mark the service operation contract like so:

```
[ServiceContract] 
interface IWebSvc1 
{ 
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)] 
    void WebMethod1() 
}
```

and use the built-in [netMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if possible to prevent flooding of your service. If you don't use queued bindings you can still implement one way over tcp/http but you run a higher risk of failed calls due to availability. If you use one-way in wcf the caller will not know about failures on the service.

Comment: I did mark the method as oneway and also implemented session on webmethod1 as I need to persist data between calls and the actual logic implementation will be in the last call of the loop. Thanks for ur time and suggestion.

Comment: I am facing SQL connectivity issue with these wcf services. As am implementing session in WCFSVC1.webmethod1, am using wshttpbinding. and when i try to connect to sql server, i get domainname/machinename$ exception. any suggessions on how to configure/host the services in IIS?

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper you should probably post this as a separate question. Once you do, let me know via comment here and I'll have a look.